# Continue for-loop despite private profile error message

Tags: r, for-loop, try-catch, vk

I have a list of user ids from VKontakte that I loop through to extract data. However, the list of ids is filled with private accounts which cause the loop to crash. Is there a way I can ignore error messages and continue the loop with the next user id on my list?

I have tried `tryCatch()` but I does not seem to work.

```r
library(vkR)


for(user in na.omit(user_id_df$user_id)) {
  
  cat("Downloading VK data for user ", user, "...\n", sep = "")
  
  # Get data on VK user
  VK_data <- tryCatch(getWallExecute(owner_id = user, count = 0))
  
  # Save each user data as a seperate rds
  saveRDS(VK_data, paste0(user, "_VK_user.rds"))
  
}
```

```
Error in vk_stop(message = response$error$error_msg, error_code = response$error$error_code) : 
  This profile is private
```

UPDATE:

I have included data.frame user_id_df

```
user_id_df <- structure(list(user_id = c(75315975L, 260432248L, 146972540L, 
                          139319097L, 74581795L, 441289912L, 139057874L, 409031930L, 51094211L, 
                          454800165L, 153893444L, 245170359L, 164009337L, 60193034L, 88824647L, 
                          160007199L, 29038672L, 303965627L, 411867598L, 227838659L, 91434822L, 
                          136816466L, 380966710L, 90695060L, 31550010L, 139747803L, 394283973L, 
                          132706991L, 66665986L, 11226063L, 20013437L, 54971153L, 136190750L, 
                          26500653L, 121766445L, 306519071L, 335255297L, 59321786L, 159745507L, 
                          145640244L, 283457719L, 161410495L, 543060909L, 439197838L, 65620234L, 
                          125886445L, 144465565L, 32416978L, 140118829L, 425256458L, 296079317L, 
                          168287322L, 273692995L, 112552215L, 244680770L, 171262442L, 85039812L, 
                          491952362L, 204601469L, 519813224L, 155014462L, 263137049L, 481696873L, 
                          217103610L, 35076657L, 137893873L, 190725766L, 247486388L, 219246226L, 
                          336022520L, 461933304L, 190319135L, 363516012L, 142188273L, 62187129L, 
                          141131903L, 518132203L, 224083708L, 203352438L, 174489946L, 137521740L, 
                          421466244L, 457935447L, 169945391L, 285490572L, 368047039L, 270575191L, 
                          275894625L, 179505995L, 536600894L, 9237680L, 39667506L, 49672847L, 
                          18317139L, 169262865L, 14312145L, 236979823L, 380162918L, 60828980L, 
                          67772465L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example

Comment: When an error occurs, what do you want `VK_data` to be? Right now you aren't actually catching the error condiction. Maybe you want `VK_data <- tryCatch(getWallExecute(owner_id = user, count = 0), error=function(e) NULL)`

Comment: First off, don't do it in a loop! The loops in R are free. What you want to do can definitely be done more elegantly and efficiently without a `for` loop. Second, give us some of your data using the `dput` function. By seeing your data, we will be able to help you better.

Comment: The solution suggested by @MrFlick did the job `VK_data <- tryCatch(getWallExecute(owner_id = user, count = 0), error=function(e) NULL). However, as requested by @Marek I have provided my data. Right now I only have 100 user ids although later I will have several 1000 so if there is a more proficient way to extract the data than loops I am very much interested. Thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: @MarcoLiedecke - have you looked into the various error handling functions of that package? Just from checking the documentation I could identify a couple already eg `has_error(response)`. So why not go about first looping through your list of and check which user_ids are well "behaved" and keep those and then repeat once more with the remaining "good"  ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Unfortunately, I do not have an authorization token to access this data and I am not able to try it out. But it should work fine for you.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vkR)

fVK_data = function(id){
  tryCatch(
    {
      id %>% getWallExecute(count = 0) %>% saveRDS(paste0(id, "_VK_user.rds"))
      return("saved")
    }, error = function(msg){
      return("Error")
    }
  )
}

user_id_df = user_id_df %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(status = map(user_id, ~fVK_data(.x))) %>% 
  unnest(status)
```

Comment: Hey @MarcoLiedecke. Have you tried my solution? It works?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Marek. I appreciate the help. Rather than actually extracting data from VKontakte the code returns a new binary column "status" stating whether or not data can be extracted from a user. "Saved" = public profile and "Error" = private profile. This is smart since I can then filter out all user_ids with private profiles which eliminates the use of tryCatch() in the original code I posted. Thanks again.

Comment: If my answer helped you in something, please do that by selecting the approved solution.